# Setting function execute order in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm newbie on Node.js, because of its asynchronous sometimes I confused how can I control function execute order. Imagin there are two functions below.

```
function login(id, pw){
 // do something
}


function getMyInfo(){
 // do something
};
```

The login() function should work firstly. and then getMyInfo(). How can I do it? I tried to this :

```
login(id, pw, function(err){
  // do something 
  if(err) return next();

  getMyInfo();
});
```

But It doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: You are only declaring the functions, they are not executed.

Comment: You need to actually accept and call the callback.

Comment: @Pierre sorry I edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "callbacks"

```
function login(id, pw, cb){
 // do something

 // after you're done:
 cb();
}

function getMyInfo(){
 // do something
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of callbacks.

Suppose you want that execution of function 2 must not take place before function 1 then call function 2 as successful callback for function 1.

They are like promises in other languages.

You can make use of Q module if you don't like callbacks.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm

Simple and Easy Tutorial